# GTK Fonts too large with openbox

Tags: fonts, gtk, openbox

I am having a problem with the default font sizes for GTK apps in openbox being too large. I do not quite understand how to fix the issue. They do not follow the settings set from within un or from gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: Try using `lxappearance`, which you can install in the typical manner.

Answer (score 4):

On startup, run whichever of these works better for you.

```
gnome-settings-daemon
lxappearance
```

Or, you can try changing your screen DPI in the file `~/.Xresources`. Just insert something like this. (Smaller numbers give smaller font sizes)

```
Xft.dpi 90
```

Comment: I use UbuntuStudio 15.10 and add lxqt PPA, I install: lxqt-metapackage lxqt-panel openbox to obtain lxqt environment, and all good next reebot, but the fonts in Gimp, Inkscape, nautilus and other apps are very small. The solution for my are intall and add at the startup: "gnome-settings-daemon". Thanks for this tuto